# Formula for the following sequence...

Tags: sequences-and-series

I play a lot of games, and usually I can figure out the formulas for level increases.  This game however, I just can't figure it out.  Any help would be much appreciated.

The Sequence:
88, 194, 319, 469, 644, 850, 1091, 1372, 1698, 2075

No matter the formula I apply or the trial and error methods I use, this is as far as I can break it down:

19, 25, 25, 31, 35, 40, 45, 51

Comment: Do you have any other data points? Also, what game is it from, so we can maybe look in the source code?

Comment: Check [OEIS](http://oeis.org) for possible clues

Comment: OEIS has nothing. My guess is that the sequence is obtained by evaluating some growth function at integer points, then rounding to the nearest integer. I've tinkered with the sequence in Maple a bit (using Lagrange interpolation and playing around with the coefficients), and whatever function it is doesn't look to be exponential. More than that I can't say.

Comment: It's from Galactic Clash by Next2Fun, ogame has the same game but their formulas do not work.

Comment: Possible data include Temp Range from 94-134°C, and material cost and time, which would involve other sequence formulas.